# Use result of Function in select projection in sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote sql query,in where clause i used function to filter some rows.

My question is :I Would like to use result function in select projection.How i can do this work because i dont like call dbo.func again to perfomance?

My query is :

```
Declare @pDate datetime=gatdate()
Select tb1.ID,tb1.Date1,dbo.Func(tb1.Date1,@pDate2)   From tb1 Where 30<=dbo.Func(tb1.Date1,@pDate2)
```

thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You've edited your question, but still confusing question. Write down about your expected results.

Comment: Moreover, it seems you are trying to compare two dates within a new SQL function. I believe it is better if you compare in where condition or in SQL directly without using unnecessary new function.

Comment: tkanks to reply,The dbo.Func() can be every function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using the Func function in select part AND the where part for performance reasons, then you can create a subquery like the following

```
DECLARE @pDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT T.ID, T.Date1, T.mDate
FROM (SELECT tb1.ID, tb1.Date1, dbo.Func(tb1.Date1,@pDate2) AS mDate FROM tb1) AS T
WHERE 30 <= T.mDate
```

However I don't know if it really helps performance, because I did no testing on that case and maybe the sql server does some optimization. If I would need to use the function i wouldn't care even use the next construct

```
SELECT tb1.ID, tb1.Date1, dbo.Func(tb1.Date1, GETDATE()) 
FROM tb1 
WHERE 30 <= dbo.Func(tb1.Date1, GETDATE())
```

Would be nice if you can make some performance test on this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but I will still answer it.

In order to use a function in an SQL query, it must accept all the parameters of SQL datatype and must return data of an SQL data type. Any type that is specifically designed for use only in Transact-SQL procedures and functions cannot be passed to or returned from a function. The function can use these T-SQL datatypes internally though.

If your function satisfies this condition, then the syntax you are using is correct.